# Sliding a background image on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background-image

The latest vogue seems to be things that move when you scroll.

Now, I have a bunch of square `div`s containing a background image scattered around a long page of content. My idea is to ever so slightly make these background images slide upwards when you scroll downwards. The background image is as wide as the square, but 1.5 times as tall.

The easy solution is to set the `backgroundPosition` to a fraction of the current `scrollTop`, but when I thought about it more, it's not altogether that simple.

Essentially, the background image of a div should be at `background-position: 0 0;` when the div is just obscured beyond the fold. Once it appears, the top position would decrease relative to scrolling, until reaching the end of the background image's bottom edge once the `div` has disappeared over the top edge of the window.

The `div`s are `float`ed within text content, so there's no way to hardcode any position values for them.

Maybe I could manage to do this on my own, but there are several considerations;

- Scrolling back and forth at any speed, and never moving the background image to a location where any part of the square `div` wasn't covered.
- Divs which appear in the middle of the page on load. It doesn't matter if the `background-position` isn't `0 0` for them initially, the important thing is that the background image moves at the same speed as all the others.
- Adjusting when the user changes the window size.

Now since this is just an extra little flair, I'm not expecting amazing browser compatibility or that this would work on mobile (although if it does, cool).

But I can't even begin to think how all of this would work out. What would be the best way to achieve this? Since the scrolling sliding thing is so popular, are there any (jQuery) plug-ins that I could utilize to build this?

Comment: css3 solution will be ok for you ?

Comment: any way it may be good start for you: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/QrWSb/ please note that you will need to recalculate pixel size of div, because % not works here

Comment: rereaded question.... best to make fiddle where you need the scrolling, i  think it easy , i not understand why your approach failed, can you show the code ?

Comment: as I understand you may need this http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/QrWSb/5/

Comment: That's not entirely what I'm after either. I have several of these `div`s on the page as images part of the content. Also, I experienced considerable lag/easing on that second fiddle. Perhaps I try something for myself and illustrate in a fiddle of my own.

Comment: last one was added easing, to show that it possible (css transition)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/QrWSb/11/

Comment: I've illustrated it here using your second fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/ANqLa/ - when there are so many of these items, the effect is so slight that you barely even notice it. That's why it should function independently for each box, so that while the distance the background moves is the same, the whole background moves from top position to end position during the time that element is actually **visible**, instead of scrolling the entire page. Do you understand better now? :)

Comment: you want something like that ? http://jsfiddle.net/ANqLa/1/

Comment: Now the images are impossibly long. The idea would be for the `background-position` to be 0% when the `t.scrollTop()` + `w.height()` = `scm.offset().top`, and to be 100% when `t.scrollTop()` - `scm.height()` = `scm.offset().top`. But I can't figure out the math required for this. Do you get what I mean? Thanks for all your help this far. :)